# Android O Background Service Lifetime affect RxJava Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-8.0-oreo

I'm working on an app and making sure it will be compatible with Android O when it comes out. In that app, I use lots RxJava and we have many Observables scattered throughout the code. My Google foo is failing me and I can't seem to find if, behind the scenes, these observables are using background services or not. Does anybody know whether or not the new background service limitations for Android O will affect my RxJava Observables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Google foo is failing me and I can't seem to find if, behind the scenes, these observables are using background services or not.

No. RxJava is not specific to Android. RxAndroid [does not have any `<service>` elements in its manifest](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/2.0.1/rxandroid/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), so it is not adding any services behind your back.

You can look at your merged manifest (see "Merged Manifest" sub-tab when editing your manifest in Android Studio 2.3+). If you see `<service>` elements that you do not recognize, those are from libraries, and you would see to see how they behave on Android 8.0+.